# Find property paths in SPARQL

Tags: sparql, rdf, wikidata, rdfs, propertypath

I took a look at the [Wikidata SPARQL Query Logs](https://iccl.inf.tu-dresden.de/web/Wikidata_SPARQL_Logs/en), and I want to find if a property path exists in a particular SPARQL Query. For example, taking a look at the [documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#propertypaths), one of the property paths was "Alternative Path", which has the syntax `elt1 | elt2`.

Is there any regular expression to find whether this path exists in a particular SPARQL Query?

Comment: I don;t get what you mean. Just write the SPARQL query, if not empty it exists - or not? OR for convenience, use an `ASK` query with the property path

Comment: Or are you asking for some REGEX to search in a query log file?

Answer (score 2):

Property Path operators (`*`, `?`, `+`, `^`, `/`, `|`) may appear in many locations (and have different meanings in each) within SPARQL queries.

Within any given SPARQL query, the `eit1` and `eit2` elements might be `<full-uri>` or `prefixed:name`, so you can't just search for (for instance) `>?<` (with or without whitespace).

I can't think of any way to search simply over one SPARQL query, never mind over many queries in a log, for those operator characters and be sure that their discovered occurrence is *as* a Property Path operator.